# How to use differentials in thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, differentiation

I wonder how to use and manipulate differential forms in thermodynamics.
I see for
$ U= αPV$, it is written $dU = αPdV + αVdP$
But how this works in terms of differentiation? (Proof)

Comment: What is $\alpha$?

Comment: That's a function of two variables U(P,V) and you are discarding the term $\alpha dPdV$. It's just a product what you differentiate. Standard calculus.

Comment: Act as if $p$ and $V$ were functions and use the product rule. This is an interesting article to get you into the world of differential forms in thermodynamics: https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2021/09/22/maxwells-relations-part-3/.

Comment: This is literally just basic calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends a bit on how rigorous you wish to be and how you define a quantity like $d U$. I like to be a bit loose and think of it like this: consider making a change in your state space that is infinitesimal, in the sense that it is smaller than anything in your system and so that something like $dU dP$ is negligibly small compared to something like $d U$. From there, this "d" operator works basically like single-variable calculus, so that the product rule applies, so that

$$d(\alpha P V) = \alpha P dV + \alpha V d P + V P d \alpha,$$

where the last term is zero if $\alpha$ is a constant.

If you want to see why something like the product rule applies, suppose that that you are changing things over a time $t$ and calculate the derivative of things with respect to $t$. Then all of your terms like $d U$ will become the numerators of derivatives with $d t$ in the denominator. Notationally and conceptually, though, people usually prefer leaving off the notion of actual changes over time.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder how to use and manipulate differential forms in thermodynamics. I see for $U= αPV$, it is written $dU = αPdV + αVdP$ But how this works in terms of differentiation?

For a function $f(x,y)$ of two variables $x$ and $y$, we write the differential:
$$
df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy\;.\tag{1}
$$

You have a function $U(V,P)$ of two variables $V$ and $P$. You simply have to use the formula given in Eq. (1) above along with the explicit form of the function $U(V,P)$ that you provided, and which I repeat below:
$$
U(V,P) = \alpha P V\;.\tag{2}
$$

---

This is basic calculus, so I don't want to give away too much of the solution, but to go just a little further, we have, from Eq. (1):
$$
dU = \frac{\partial U}{\partial V}dV + \frac{\partial U}{\partial P}dP\;.\tag{3}
$$

Now use Eq. (2) to fill in the proper concrete expressions for the abstract partial derivatives denoted in Eq. (3).

Comment: Nice explanation